# Windows Reset my PC gives error

Tags: windows, windows-10, reset

I'm trying to reset my pc with the Windows 10 Reset my PC feature. Each time I try to do it, it gives me the following error:

[image]

I have tried:

- Restoring my PC to the lastest backup taken by System Restore
- Running the System File Checker (SFC) tool to check for corrupt files

I found [an article](https://www.makeuseof.com/fix-there-was-a-problem-resetting-your-pc-error-in-windows-10/) that said to rename the C:\Windows\System32\System and Software files, but I did not do that as it can prevent restarts and really damage your pc.

I tried disabling reagent.exe (also from the article), but then I cannot restore without an installation USB which I did not receive as I just got the laptop. It's a Microsoft Surface Book 2. I can make such a USB if I would need one to fix this.

Can anybody suggest any options I can try to reset my laptop and keep my files?

Comment: In order to determine the reason the Reset failed you would have to provide the log files that were generated.  The location of these logs files are well documented, however, I am going to guess Windows is not actually booting?  If that is the case then you will need a Windows 10 installation disk to resolve your issue.  be sure you create the system recovery disk specific to the [MSB2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/creating-and-using-a-usb-recovery-drive-for-surface-677852e2-ed34-45cb-40ef-398fc7d62c07).

Comment: After you [download](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/creating-and-using-a-usb-recovery-drive-for-surface-677852e2-ed34-45cb-40ef-398fc7d62c07#bkmk_download) the recovery disk use [**these**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/creating-and-using-a-usb-recovery-drive-for-surface-677852e2-ed34-45cb-40ef-398fc7d62c07#bkmk_reset_surface) instructions to Reset your MSB2

Comment: Actually, after I click OK, it restores the laptop and I can still use it. Some programs don't start up anymore (Brave browser and Remote Desktop Manager), but apart from those, I can still use the laptop. I'm looking into the recovery tools now.

Comment: Apparently the Logitech webcam caused problems. I tried reinstalling 7 times, each time trying something different until I unplugged the webcam and it worked like a charm. I think that might've been the problem from the start. ‍♂️

Thanks for your help everybody!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, get the Surface Book hardware diagnostic tools and run those to see if there is a hardware error.  The message suggests there might be.

If there are no hardware errors, then use the Microsoft USB to reload Windows.

Good luck with this.